# PowerShell 2 on Windows Server Core

Tags: powershell, windows-server, powershell-2.0

I have two machines, `Windows Server Core 2016` and `Windows 10 Enterprise`.

From cmd, executing `PowerShell.exe` and then `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` outputs version 5.1 for both machines.

From cmd, executing `PowerShell.exe -Version 2` and then `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` outputs,

- Version 5.1 for Windows Server Core 2016
- Version 2.0 for Windows 10 Enterprise

Is there something that needs installed on the Windows Core Server 2016 to get the `-Version 2` argument to work properly?

Running `Get-WindowsFeature PowerShell*` on the server machine outputs the following,

```
Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[X] Windows PowerShell                                  PowerShellRoot                 Installed
[X] Windows PowerShell 5.1                              PowerShell                     Installed
[X] Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine                       PowerShell-V2                  Installed
```

*Note - I'm aware PowerShell 2.0 is deprecated, this is to ensure legacy scripts remain working while we migrate them to new version of PowerShell*

Comment: What version of Windows Server?  What version of Windows is your desktop running?  Edit your question, please do not submit a temporary comment.

Answer (score 1):

V2 is built into the OS, it just needs to be enabled and there is nothing more needed. However, v2 should no longer be used as per Microsoft.

> [Windows PowerShell 2.0 Deprecation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation)
>
> We recently announced that Windows PowerShell 2.0 is being deprecated
>   in the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. ***Deprecation is a process
>   whereby technologies or applications are marked as legacy, signalling
>   to users that they may be removed in the future, and that should move
>   away from them and towards newer alternatives.***

This really applies to all recent Windows OS's client and server.
v2 is disabled by default on all recent OS versions for a reason.

See also:

> [Securing Windows Workstations: Developing a Secure Baseline](https://adsecurity.org/?tag=disable-powershell-version-2)
>
> Securing workstations against modern threats is challenging. It seems
>   like every week there’s some new method attackers are using to
>   compromise a system and user credentials. Post updated on March 8th,
>   2018 with recommended event IDs to audit. The best way to create a
>   secure Windows workstation is to download the Microsoft Security
>   Compliance Manager …

Comment: It has been enabled (i.e. `Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine`) unless you're implying that there's something else that needs enabled?